# Accessing data inside JSON Array with C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, unity-game-engine

I am writing a C# script in unity to get the weather of the location the player is in.
I am almost done, all I have to do is extract the data from the JSON file the weather API returned. I am using SimpleJSON to read and extract the JSON. The JSON looks something like this:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": (floating point number),
    "lat": (floating point number)
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 804,
      "main": "Clouds",
      "description": "overcast clouds",
      "icon": "04n"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 292.01,
    "feels_like": 292.12,
    "temp_min": 291.15,
    "temp_max": 293.15,
    "pressure": 1018,
    "humidity": 72
  },
  "visibility": 9000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 1.5,
    "deg": 130
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 100
  },
  "dt": 1594239812,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 1308,
    "country": "COUNTRY-CODE",
    "sunrise": 1594178675,
    "sunset": 1594235893
  },
  "timezone": 7200,
  "id": 2954172,
  "name": "CITY",
  "cod": 200
}
```

I need to access the "description" in the "weather" array. However I could not figure out how to get it to work.
This is my C# code:

```
var PARSED_JSON_2 = JSON.Parse(JSON_DATA_2);
var weather_description = PARSED_JSON_2["weather"][2]; //returns null
//I also tried something like this:
var weather_description = PARSED_JSON_2["weather"]["description"][2]; //returns null
var weather_description = PARSED_JSON_2["weather"]["description"][2].Value; //Returns nothing.
```

A Debug.Log would show  an empty string.

I tried to follow this reference here: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON

(In a nutshell I need to access an element inside of a JSON array, but I can't figure out how to. Any help is appreciated.)

Comment: needs to be done with SimpleJSON? or could you use any other third party library?

Comment: I am on linux, so my options aren't as abundant.
I found SimpleJSON to work best up until this point, but if you have suggestion, I would try it aswell.
As long as I can figure out how to access the element "description" inside the "weather" array of the json file.

Comment: you can create C#  Class  and deserialize it to C# object. You can update field as per your wish

Comment: I'll suggest to use Newtonsoft (I don't know if it works on linux or not), or you can use my JsonManager (https://github.com/EricBatlle/SimpleUnityUtils/tree/master/Assets/Simple_JsonManager)

Comment: @Lotan is it cross platform / does it work with unity?
I am aiming to make this cross platform, mainly targeting mobile devices.
Oh, lol. I take that back - Just saw the using UnityEngine;

Comment: Yes it is. Anyway I think the problem will be solved if you do PARSED_JSON_2["weather"][0], notice that inside your array, you have only one Object. If it works but it's not clear I can post an answer explaining it better ^^

Comment: Well there only is one single item in `weather` ... In general you could also use [`JsonUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html)

Comment: That works, thank you!
(Can you explain why you used this? I don't  really know JSON.)

My inital thought process was:
1. Access the weather structure.
2. Specify the index of the field I want. ("description" / [2])

Comment: @acoder because you are trying to access an index that can't exist ... `2` would refer to the third element in the array ... but there is only **one** with index `0`

Comment: Oh now I get it.
I thought that the array was specified INSIDE of "weather".
So "id" would be 0, "main" would be 1 and so on - but that isn't the case.
Off I go learning JSON arrays!

`"weather": [
                {
                "id": 804,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "overcast clouds",
                "icon": "04n"
                }
            ], `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access an index `2` that does not exist. There is only **one single** element in the `weather` array. In this case that `SimpleJSON` library simply returns `null` instead of throwing a proper exception!

You should rather use the index `0`

```
var weather_description = PARSED_JSON_2["weather"][0];
```

---

In general you could also use the [`JsonUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html) and deserialize your complete array into a proper c# class representation. Then you would immediately see how many elements the array/s has/have or get the expected exceptions properly.

Yours would look like

```
[Serializable]
public class Root
{
    public Coord coord;
    public Weather[] weather;
    public string @base;
    public Main main;
    public int visibility;
    public Wind wind;
    public Clouds clouds;
    public double dt;
    public Sys sys;
    public int timezone;
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public int cod;
}

[Serializable]
public class Coord
{
    public float lon;
    public float lat;
}

[Serializable]
public class Weather
{
    public int id;
    public string main;
    public string description;
    public string icon;
}

[Serializable]
public class Main
{
    public float temp;
    public float feels_like;
    public float temp_min;
    public float temp_max;
    public float pressure;
    public float humidity;
}

[Serializable]
public class Wind
{
    public float speed;
    public float deg;
}

[Serializable]
public class Clouds
{
    public int all;
}

[Serializable]
public class Sys
{
    public int type;
    public int id;
    public string country;
    public int sunrise;
    public int sunset;
}
```

And then you would do e.g.

```
var root = JsonUtility.FromJson<Root>(JSON_DATA_2);
var weather = root.weather[0];
```

The big advantage of this approach would be that you can also directly see the result in the Inspector of Unity by writing into a

```
public class JsonTester : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Input")]
    [Tooltip("Copy your json string here and call \"Test\" from the Context menu")]
    [SerializeField] [TextArea] private string _testJson;

    [Header("Output")]
    [SerializeField] private Root _receivedJson;

    [ContextMenu(nameof(Test))]
    private void Test()
    {
        VisualizeJson(_testJson);
    }

    public void VisualizeJson(string json)
        JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, _receivedJson);
    }
}
```

[image]